# How to stop lxml from generating html entities when writing utf-8 documents

Tags: python, xml, xslt, lxml

I need to process XML files containing text with Romanian characters, (text like 'licenţe şi mărci').

After processing this text ends up in html documents.
If at the final step I output the content using something like:

```
doc.write(path, encoding='utf-8', method='xml' )
```

**NOTE**: `doc` above is an instance of `lxml.etree.ElementTree`

I get something like:

```
<span id="123">licenţe şi mărci</span>
```

Everything looks fine (i.e. Romanian chars are not converted to html entities).

If I do use the html encoding method

```
doc.write(path, encoding='utf-8', method='html' )
```

I get something like:

```
<span id="128927">licen&#355;e &#351;i m&#259;rci</span>
```

Although the document looks ok in the browser, the text in the document is also used by another process which extracts the text and uses it for some diff-ing jobs which get completely confused by the html entities.

Although using the `xml` as the method argument to `etree.ElementTree.write` seems to solve my current problem, it feels wrong since I really want to generate `html` files and may behave badly in other contexts.

Is there a way to write a document as html (using `method='html'`) without having lxml replace non ascii chars with html entities ?

---

After @mzjn 's question it turns out that the story is a bit more complicated.

Here's a minimal code that reproduces the problem:

```
from lxml import etree
from os import path

def process( method, out_name ):

    # the doc
    x = etree.XML('<span id="123">licenţe şi mărci</span>')
    tree = etree.ElementTree(x)

    #do some processing
    modifiedTree = modifyDoc(tree)

    # write the result
    modifiedTree.write(out_name, encoding='utf-8',  method=method)

def modifyDoc(tree):
    root = tree.getroot()

    doNothingTransformPath = _absolutePath('transform.xslt')
    transform_doc = etree.parse(doNothingTransformPath)
    transform = etree.XSLT(transform_doc)
    return transform(root)

def _absolutePath(relative):
    return path.abspath(path.join( __file__ , '..', relative))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    process( 'xml', 'out1.xml')
    process( 'html', 'out2.html')
```

where (in this example) the XSLT transform (doing nothing) is:

-- transform.xslt --

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="no"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:copy-of select="/"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If I don't pass the document through the XSLT transform the output does **not** contain HTML entities, when passed through the modifyDoc function (i.e. applying an xslt transform) the output is changed as described above, (i.e. when using `method='html'` the output contains HTML entities).

So running the program above outputs two files:

-- out1.xml --

```
<span id="123">licenţe şi mărci</span>
```

and
-- out2.html --

```
<span id="123">licen&#x163;e &#x15F;i m&#x103;rci</span>
```

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]? It's not completely clear how to reproduce this.

Comment: @mzjn Tank you, for your comment. Trying to reproduce the problem in a minimal sample puzzled me completely since everything seems to work fine. Looking through my code and isolating the minimal processing that reproduces  the problem made me realise that it is the application of a xslt transform during the document processing that seems to cause the HTML entity insertions (see updated problem description).

Comment: It works with `<xsl:output method="xml" indent="no" encoding="UTF-8"/>`. According to https://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#xslt-result-objects, the default encoding is ASCII.

Comment: Thank you, very much, you are a star !!  Indeed, by setting the encoding in the xsl:output everything is fixed.

Comment: For me it also works with `<xsl:output method="html" indent="no"/>`.

Comment: yes, the issue is not the method (in the xsl:output) it was the fact that I did not specify the encoding in the `<xsl:output  encoding='UTF-8' />`  tag.  This was creating the HTML entities but only when using  `doc.write( doc_name , encoding='utf-8',  method='html')`

Comment: Glad you got a solution. The real problem, though, is that "another process which extracts the text" isn't real HTML-capable.